# Python Pandas inferring column datatypes

Tags: python, pandas, profiling

I am reading JSON files into dataframes. The dataframe might have some String (object) type columns, some Numeric (int64 and/or float64), and some datetime type columns. When the data is read in, the datatype is often incorrect (ie datetime, int and float will often be stored as "object" type). I want to report on this possibility. (ie a column is in the dataframe as "object" (String), but it is actually a "datetime").

The problem i have is that when i use ***pd.to_numeric*** and ***pd.to_datetime*** they will both evaluate and try to convert the column, and many times it ends up depending on which of the two I call last... (I was going to use ***convert_objects()*** which works but that is depreciated, so wanted a better option).

The code I am using to evaluate the dataframe column is (i realize a lot of the below is redundant, but I have written it this way for readability):

```
try:
   inferred_type = pd.to_datetime(df[Field_Name]).dtype
   if inferred_type == "datetime64[ns]":
      inferred_type = "DateTime"
except:
   pass
try:
   inferred_type = pd.to_numeric(df[Field_Name]).dtype
   if inferred_type == int:
      inferred_type = "Integer"
   if inferred_type == float:
      inferred_type = "Float"
except:
   pass
```

Comment: It such a shame that it's been deprecated. It is a glorious method.

Comment: convert_objects is deprecated by [infer_objects](https://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/generated/pandas.DataFrame.infer_objects.html) is not

Comment: @itzjustricky infer_objects won't even recognize ['1', '2', '3'] as being numeric. 

pd.DataFrame(['1', '2', '3']).infer_objects().dtypes returns "object"

Comment: convert_objects might be eliminated, but you have [infer_objects](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.infer_objects.html#pandas.DataFrame.infer_objects) and [convert_dtypes](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.convert_dtypes.html), which might be useful

Answer (score 15):

I came across the same problem of having to figure out column types for incoming data where the type is not known beforehand (from a database read in my case). I couldn't find a good answer here on SO, or by reviewing the Pandas source code. I solved it using this function:

```
def _get_col_dtype(col):
        """
        Infer datatype of a pandas column, process only if the column dtype is object. 
        input:   col: a pandas Series representing a df column. 
        """

        if col.dtype == "object":
            # try numeric
            try:
                col_new = pd.to_datetime(col.dropna().unique())
                return col_new.dtype
            except:
                try:
                    col_new = pd.to_numeric(col.dropna().unique())
                    return col_new.dtype
                except:
                    try:
                        col_new = pd.to_timedelta(col.dropna().unique())
                        return col_new.dtype
                    except:
                        return "object"
        else:
            return col.dtype
```

Answer (score 6):

Deep in the Pandas API there actually is a function that does a half decent job.

```
import pandas as pd

infer_type = lambda x: pd.api.types.infer_dtype(x, skipna=True)
df.apply(infer_type, axis=0)


# DataFrame with column names & new types

df_types = pd.DataFrame(df.apply(pd.api.types.infer_dtype, axis=0)).reset_index().rename(columns={'index': 'column', 0: 'type'})
```

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.api.types.infer_dtype.html#pandas.api.types.infer_dtype

Since

> The inference rules are the same as during normal Series/DataFrame construction.

consider [to_numeric](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html) for int/floats
eg: `df['amount'] = pd.to_numeric(df['amount'], errors='ignore')`

Comment: didn't seem to work for me, returned all string even though there were some int, float, and bool columns

Answer (score 5):

This worked best for me:

```
    df.convert_dtypes()
```

Comment: Easy and worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

One solution to get it to infer dtypes is to get it to write the data to a CSV using `StringIO`, and then read it back.

Answer (score 1):

Working off of BeigeBruceWayne's answer

```
df_types = pd.DataFrame(df_final.apply(pd.api.types.infer_dtype, axis=0)).reset_index().rename(columns={'index': 'column', 0: 'type'})

loop_types = df_types.values.tolist()

for col in loop_types:
    if col[1] == 'mixed':
        pass
    else:
        if col[1] == 'decimal':
            data_type = 'float64'
        elif col[1] == 'string':
            data_type = 'str'
        elif col[1] == 'integer':
            data_type = 'int'
        elif col[1] == 'floating':
            data_type = 'float64'
        elif col[1] == 'date':
            data_type = 'datetime64'
        else:
            data_type = col[1]
        df_final[col[0]] = df_final[col[0]].astype(data_type)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try e.g.

```
df['field_name'] = df['field_name'].astype(np.float64)
```

(assuming that `import numpy as np`)

Comment: Thanks. How can i check for datetime using the above strategy?

Comment: `df['field_name'] = pd.to_datetime(df['field_name'])`

Comment: Still experiencing the same problem. Columns seem to be able to be evaluated as both datetime and float types.

Comment: Wait, are you trying convert a column to see if it throws an error? Are you suggesting you don't know what types your data columns have? That's awkward; I'd suggest you define your dataset first. Dates in Epoch time can look like int for example, so a conversion to int or to datetime will both work.

Comment: Yes, that's my approach (in lieu of a better solution)... I don't think this is the best way to do things, but I simply don't have control over the dataset that will be read into the dataframe (hence the problem). Any other suggestions welcome!!

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively: Pandas allows you to explicity define datatypes when creating a dataframe.  You pass in a dictionary with column names as the key and the data type desired as the value.

[Documentation Here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html#pandas.DataFrame) for the standard constructor

Or you can cast the column's type after importing into the data frame

eg:
`df['field_name'] = df['field_name'].astype(np.date_time)`